# How do you say 'member-elect' in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, lenguaje-jurídico

In English, the term "member-elect" refers to a person having been elected to a legislative body, but *not yet having been sworn into office*.

I have found on Google Translate:

> miembro electo

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

According to the RAE, *[electo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=electo)* means exactly the same as it does in English

Comment: Hadn't been familiar with https://enclave.rae.es. Muchas gracias.